# how to use the optimised cutoff point to improve the predictive model in R?

Tags: r, optimization, similarity, prediction, roc

I am a bit confuse of how to use a cut-off score to improve a precision of my predictive model.
here is a sample of data:

I have a dataset (matrix) which looks like:

```
> data_test
                1         2         3         4         5        6
KRT6B    0.807688  1.097187 -0.390313  0.644938 -0.187188 1.200688
CXCL1    0.255250 -0.134917  1.886083  0.433417  0.267583 0.996583
S100A8  -1.694800  0.012900 -0.314800 -0.368600 -0.750100 2.864700
S100A7  -0.417500  0.989000 -0.887000 -0.914500 -0.909000 4.485000
HORMAD1 -0.124750 -0.304083 -0.911050  5.426917  0.042250 6.490917
CLCA2    4.243417  0.032583 -1.750917 -1.551250  1.249917 1.494417
```

the colnames are samples and rownames are Genes.

so to find a cut-off point I generate a score for the cut-offs by adding up the expression of each column and assign it to predictor:

```
predictor <- colSums(data_test)

> predictor
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
 3.069305  1.692670 -2.367997  3.670922 -0.286538 17.532305
```

and the response for it:

```
> response
[1] norm high norm low  norm high
Levels: high norm low
```

I used pROC package to generate a ROC curve and find the optimised cut-off (with youden index value/ J statistic):

```
library(pROC)
rocobj <- roc(response,predictor)
cutpoint <- coords(rocobj,x='best',input='threshold',best.method = 'youden')

 threshold specificity sensitivity 
 0.7030660   1.0000000   0.6666667
```

So, now I have my optimised cut-off point but I cannot understand how can I use this optimised cut-off (sort of a score!) to improve the precision of my predictive model.
In several papers they've used this approach and at the end they've shown that the similarity level of the predictive model has been improved by using the new cut-off point. I tried to understand but I am stock here cause I don't get it! (I mean the next step!). They didn't mention how they checked the similarity or how they implement the new cut-off point in my case the score to improve their method.

Could someone give me a good explanation for the next step?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my messy explanation.

Comment: I guess one question you should ask is: what was your predictive model before having a threshold? What are you predicting and how?

Comment: Also, please upgrade to the development version of pROC (type `install.packages("devtools"); devtools::install_github("xrobin/pROC")`) and carefully look at the output and new warning.